# What is the correct mime type for .min.map javascript source files?

Tags: javascript

**plain/text** or **application/json**?

I am unable to locate any mention of it, my google-fu is weak today.

It does not mention it in this Source Map Revision document that I can see.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?hl=en_US&pli=1&pli=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google's JavaScript CDN serves jQuery's source map as `application/json`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer :)